# I can not get data from this.state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I receive JSON from my back end, I save it in my state and I want to use it in props in another react component, but it doesn't work.

I try to show need date like that in props of my component - `{this.state.movies["0"]["title"]}`, but it doesn't work.

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      movies: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getAllMoviesForMainPage();
  }

  getAllMoviesForMainPage() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:8080/showAll")
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ movies: response.data })
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="qwerty">
        <MainPageComponent />
        <div className='moviePreviewGrid'>
          <Router>
            <div className="moviePreviewGrid-row">
              <div className="moviePreviewGrid-col">
                <MoviePreview
                  Title={this.state.movies["2"]["title"]}
                  MoviePreviewAvatar={DrivePoster}
                  SeeMore="unrelated long string here"
                />
                <NavLink to="/showByTitle/Драйв">
                  <button type="button" className="myBtn">See more</button>
                </NavLink>
              </div>
```

and structure of my JSON

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Джокер",
        "releaseDate": "2019",
        "genre": "Триллер, драма, криминал",
        "duration": "122 минуты",
        "rating": 8.7,
        "criticReviews": [
            {
                "criticName": "Anton",
                "review": "anton review"
            },
            {
                "criticName": "OldCritic",
                "review": "old review"
            }
        ],
        "userReviews": [
            {
                "nickName": "Igor",
                "review": "igor review"
            },
            {
                "nickName": "Nik",
                "review": "nik review"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Ирландец",
        "releaseDate": "2019",
        "genre": "Драма, триллер, криминал, биографический",
        "duration": "209 минут",
        "rating": 8.4,
        "criticReviews": [
            {
                "criticName": "YoungCritic",
                "review": "young review"
            }
        ],
        "userReviews": [
            {
                "nickName": "Gambit",
                "review": "gambit review"
            },
            {
                "nickName": "Andrew",
                "review": "andrew review"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Драйв",
        "releaseDate": "2011",
        "genre": "Боевик, драма",
        "duration": "100 минут",
        "rating": 7.8,
        "criticReviews": [
            {
                "criticName": "Critic",
                "review": "review"
            }
        ],
        "userReviews": [
            {
                "nickName": "Anton",
                "review": "anton review"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "Последний человек на Земле",
        "releaseDate": "2015",
        "genre": "Комедия",
        "duration": "22 минуты",
        "rating": 7.3,
        "criticReviews": [
            {
                "criticName": "NewCritic",
                "review": "new review"
            }
        ],
        "userReviews": [
            {
                "nickName": "Atomf7",
                "review": "atomf7 review"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "title": "Интерстеллар",
        "releaseDate": "2014",
        "genre": "Фантастика, драма, приключения",
        "duration": "169 минут",
        "rating": 8.6,
        "criticReviews": [
            {
                "criticName": "Nik",
                "review": "nik review"
            }
        ],
        "userReviews": [
            {
                "nickName": "Alice",
                "review": "alice review"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

and i wont to have for example title of first movie

Comment: what error does it show

Comment: That's not JSON, it's an array with a JSON string inside it.

Comment: I pass from my controller just an object and in postman writes that it JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first render movies are not already fetched from the api.

So you need to conditionally render it.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default class Test extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      movies: [],
      loading: true
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getAllMoviesForMainPage();
  }

  getAllMoviesForMainPage() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:8080/showAll")
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ movies: response.data, loading: false })
      })
  }

  render() {
    const { loading, movies } = this.state;

    if (loading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          {movies.length > 0 ? (
            <div>First movie title: {movies[0].title}</div>
          ) : (
            <div>No movies</div>
          )}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

You can check this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-brook-g2y6k) using a fake api.

Answer (score 2):

In the first init, the `this.state.movies` has a length of 0 so `this.state.movies["2"]["title"]` of course would have no value at all
because `getAllMoviesForMainPage` is **async** (axios call) and takes a little longer to complete, so first you must give it an initial value and only when the request completes you can give it the real value.

example:

```
<MoviePreview
  Title={this.state.movies.length > 0 ? this.state.movies[2].title : ""}
  MoviePreviewAvatar={DrivePoster}
/>
```

Usually a state, `isLoading` is used for this case. So you can know when you received your data.

Comment: i'm tried it, but it still don't work with this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined in console

Comment: @qwerty the condition was initially wrong in this answer, I fixed it so now it should work (unless you receive less than 3 movies).

Answer (score 1):

You are making a GET request in `componentDidMount` which is `async` so until the promise is resolve in `.then(..` your state does not contain `response.data` in `movies`.

The important thing to remember is component gets re-render every time you do `this.setState(..` , so before you do setState in your `getAllMoviesForMainPage` method, the initial render will happen and it will contain an empty array in `this.state.movies` that you have defined in constructor

Also since your response contains array of objects, you would be using `movies['2'].title` instead of `movies['2']['title']`

So your render method should contain something like this to show movie preview:

```
    <div className="moviePreviewGrid-col">
      {this.state.movies.length ? (
        <MoviePreview
          Title={this.state.movies['2'].title}
          MoviePreviewAvatar={DrivePoster}
          SeeMore="unrelated long string here"
        />
      ) : (
        <PlaceHolderPreview />
      )}
      <NavLink to="/showByTitle/Драйв">
        <button type="button" className="myBtn">
          See more
        </button>
      </NavLink>
    </div>
```

`PlaceHolderPreview` can be your another component that will show -- well a placeholder for preview.

Hope it all makes sense.

Comment: _"`movies['2'].title` instead of `movies['2']['title']`"_ both are [equally valid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4968406/1218980). The best practice though would be to use a number for the index within the square brackets: `movies[2].title`.